# Postgres Copy from file- changing the value of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to copy the content of the file to postgres.
The file's content is something like this:

`2014-06-13;Platform;-38193438.530000;EUR`

Here is my code for copy:

```
COPY statistics(referencedate, platform, total, currency)
FROM '/home/output.csv'
WITH DELIMITER ';';
```

This copy command works, and the lines are inserted. But instead of the word "Platform", I would need to insert the name of the platform for example 'AAA'. My ugly workaround would be running a script and modifying the original file prior to COPY. But I don't really believe that there is not a more elegant solution for this.

I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
 COPY statistics(referencedate, platform, total, currency)
 FROM '/home/output.csv'
 WITH DELIMITER ';' AND platform AS 'AAA';
```

Comment: This is not possible with the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using something like:

```
`COPY ... FROM PROGRAM 'awk -F ; ''{ printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,"AAA",$3,$4,$5; }'''`
```

(untested, and `PROGRAM` is 9.3 only)

i.e. using a filter on the input file as you pipe it in. The filter can be whatever you want. A Perl/Python/Awk/Sed/whatever snippet or script.

`COPY` its self does not have what you want built in directly. In this simple case, you *could* `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN platform SET DEFAULT 'AAA`' and `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN platform SET NOT NULL` on the column you wish to change, then `COPY .... (referencedate, total, currency) FROM ...`, but it's a bit cumbersome at best.